# What is a noun for "a person holding the first rank” (in school)?

Tags: word-request

> Ranked by total GPA, The [ noun here] of our school is Jack.

Does "forerunner" or "first-ranker" work?

Answer (score 1):

**[forerunner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forerunner)** means "someone or something who came earlier than something else".  That's not what we mean.  You're probably thinking of *[frontrunner](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frontrunner)*.

**first-ranker** is understandable but not idiomatic.  *First-ranking* is acceptable as an adjective, but I don't think I have ever heard the noun *first-ranker* used.

The highest-ranking student in a class is usually called the *[valedictorian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valedictorian)*, if you're looking for something specifically applicable to students.

Comment: I upvoted this, but wanted to mention that you wouldn’t call Jack the valedictorian until it’s time for the class to graduate. You could say, “Jack is poised to be the valedictorian,” or, as you suggest, “Jack is the frontrunner for valedictorian.”

Comment: @J.R. - Good point.

Answer (score 0):

In our region, we call this person the **topper** of the school/examinations/etc. Being a topper implies that you're the one who got the highest GPA in the entire class/school/region. It has nothing to do with valedictorian/farewell functions.

Moreover, as opposed to what J.R. pointed out in another comment, you can be a topper at any time around the year. You can be a topper in the monthly tests, or in the half yearly exams, well before the time the class will graduate.

It does have a Google Dictionary entry for it:

> an exceptionally good person or thing. (British, informal, dated)

While it doesn't refer to marks specifically, you'll surely get the idea of this context if you just google "cbse india topper" - for an idea of the high frequency with which it's used in India.